# Значение слова АБРАКАДАБРА

Tags: этимология

Смысл и происхождение слова **абракадабра**.

Comment: Может быть, напишите хотя бы "подскажите, пожалуйста"? Тут все-таки живые люди, а не википедия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Абракадабра --

1) магическая формула, таинственное слово, которому приписывалась чудодейственная сила. Его произносили как заклинание, писали на амулетах. Утверждалось, что оно помогало при лихорадке, горячке, малярии, зубной боли. Чтобы излечиться от лихорадки, нужно было написать это слово на пергаменте или дощечке одиннадцать раз так, чтобы получился треугольник, затем носить этот амулет в ладанке на шее определенное количество дней, по истечении которых бросить написанное в быстрый поток, не разворачивая, стоя к воде спиной. По одной из версий, в переводе с древнееврейского слово "авракадавра" значит "Скройся, нечистый". По преданию, оно было одновременно и именем идола Сирийского, усвоенного древними греками, а затем перешедшего и в другие языки и суеверные традиции;

2) непонятный набор слов, бессмыслица.

[Ср.-лат. abracadabra -- надпись на амулете, употреблявшаяся как магическая формула < греч. abrakadabra. Этимология греческого слова неясна: или от греч. abraxos -- обозначение божества и др.-евр. dabar -- слово, или от греч. abrasax (или abraxas) -- магическое, мистическое слово, или от др.-евр. arba-dak-arba от arba -- четыре.]

Answer (score 0):

"Слово «абракадабра», означающее "бессмыслица, вздор", было придумано еще в Древнем Риме, именно придумано, составлено из набора звуков, не имеющих в отдельности какого либо смысла. Это слово использовалось жрецами как магическая формула, писали его и на амулетах, потому что считалось, что оно обладает таинственной силой." (Крылов Г.А., ЭС).

Забавным выглядит утверждение, что при составлении слова А. латинянами (или их подражателями?) использовался генератор случайных чисел (/букв/звуков). Полученное таким способом слово вряд ли окажется удобопроизносимым и уже совсем никакой надежды не остается, что оно сохранит хоть какие – то признаки принадлежности к латыни. Если бы слово А. представляло собой хаотичный набор букв, его перспективы (запомниться и) закрепиться в языке были бы призрачны, а ведь оно существует и фиксируется на письме (не только на амулетах), в устной речи, и даже в песне.

Если согласиться с предположением, что слово А. состоит из элементов латинского происхождения, тогда  «аб» (лат.), это приставка означающая отрицание. Корень «рокада» (лат.) может означать движение по кольцевому (круговому) пути, вращение… Такое слово давно в ходу у военных, да и градостроители применяют его в отношении автомобильных (и железных) дорог, служащих для объезда города большегрузами (Рока́да / рока́дный путь, от фр. rocade «объездная дорога»). В Румынии (и не только) шахматисты называют этим словом ход короля, который мы называем рокировкой. Завершает слово А. постфикс «абра», звучащий как рефрен и позволяющий при его написании (гравировке) замкнуть все слово в кольцо, в бесконечное слово - заклинание (подобно бесконечному слову – признанию «…люблюблюблю…», выгравированному на обручальном кольце https://sunmag.me/novosti/11-02-2016-istoriya-lyubvi-lilya-brik-i-vladimir-mayakovskij.html
).

Похоже, что слово А. «сконструировано» для написания замкнутого (волшебного?)   кольца из букв (кириллицы / латиницы), причем приставка «аб» отрицает возможность такой формы записи.  Таким образом А., это слово – противоречие, слово – абсурд. 
Даль В.И., а вслед за ним и ЭСБЕ, свидетельствуют, что первичное значение слова А., - род заговора (заклинания) врачующего болезни. Возможно, что это и есть та самая причина (мотивировка), по которой возникло слово А.

В корпусе русского языка (КРЯ) насчитывается 255 вхождений слова «абракадабр(а/ой/у/е/ы)». Причем, в подавляющем большинстве случаев слово А. употребляется в значении: бессмыслица, галиматья, околесица, тарабарщина, чушь. Редкими исключениями из общего правила оказались три вхождения слова А. со значениями: сказочное заклинание, лит. издательство, кумир с сомнительной репутацией.
«Рассказывают, что они поклоняются Абракадабре и всякого вступающего в их согласие заставляют предварительно разжевать раскаленный уголь, ― и при этом произнести ту страшную клятву, которую произносит в «Князе Серебряном» колдун мельник: «Шикалу! [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Фельетоны и юморески из «Свистка» (1863)]».

Важно отметить, что самое раннее вхождение (в КРЯ) слова А. датируется 1862 годом. Странно, что столь полезное, обладающее чудодейственной силой древнее (европейское?) слово стало известно (пишущим на русском языке) так поздно, - более века спустя после эпохи заимствований (при Петре).  Допустим, что слово было табуированным и писалось только на амулетах, но тогда трудно объяснить почему все упоминания слова А. в КРЯ (за редчайшими исключениями)  имеют (негативный) смысл: чепуха, чушь, вздор. Почтения к этому слову не наблюдается.

«Любопытно было бы послушать, как осадил бы он г. Антоновича за все эти «абракадабры». Но не все же Базаровы, и мы можем уважить искренность верования, в какой бы суровой форме она ни выражалась. [М. Н. Катков. Роман Тургенева и его критики (1862)]».

Иноязычные писатели к слову А. относятся уважительнее: «It was as though the very form of the face, without will or intention on the part of the possessor, acted hypnotically upon its beholder. The Arabians believed in the magic power of the word Abracadabra to cast a spell. [Theodore Dreiser. The "Genius", book I-II (1915)]».

В корпусе английского языка имеется 47 вхождений слова «abracadabra», причем 46 из них относятся к ХХ веку (из числа которых 12 приходится на 1940 г.). 
Короче говоря, найти подтверждения «глубокой древности» происхождения слова А. не удается.

Гораздо раньше чем А., в КРЯ начинает упоминаться слово «крокодил» (К.), которое близко к А. по своему составу (к+рокада+ил). Такое толкование слова К. выглядит оригинальным только на первый взгляд. Смысл корня (рокада = вращение) в слове К. вполне раскрывается цитатой из статьи «Крокодилы» (см. Википедию): «Хотя жевать крокодилы не могут, крупную добычу они легко разрывают на подходящие по размерам куски при помощи своей мускулистой шеи и сильных челюстей, после чего проглатывают их целиком. Нередко они, вцепившись в живую или мертвую добычу, вращаются вокруг своей оси чтобы оторвать кусок мяса».
Наблюдать этот процесс сегодня может каждый (благодаря  демонстрации научно - популярных фильмов по ТВ). Зрелище, когда крокодил терзает добычу вращением своего тела наверняка произвело большое впечатление на первых наблюдателей, а значит вполне могло послужить важнейшим признаком (из всех отличительных), по которому это животное и было названо.